# Creating elements using values from an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

Hey I need some help here with my array. I can see that with `document.getElementById` that it catches my values, but I want the value to be a background style in a div. I know it looks very messed with `<li>` and a `<div>` inside of that but I'm really lost and I can't get it to work.

I need to make a element for every item in the array and give them of them the value as a background-color.

If what I'm asking doesn't make sense, I'm sorry as it's very late ;-)

```js
var noteColors = [
  { name: "red", value: "#FF396D" }, 
  { name: "green", value: "#C6DD2A" }, 
  { name: "blue", value: "#55C7F0" }, 
  { name: "purple", value: "#F64FC2" }, 
  { name: "yellow", value: "#F6DC2C" }];
```

```html
<div id="note_colors_wrapper">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var index;
    var text = "<ul id='colorss'>";

    for (index = 0; index < noteColors.length; index++) {
      text += "<li class='ol'>" + noteColors[index].value + "</li>";
    }
    text += "</ul>";
    document.getElementById("note_colors_wrapper").innerHTML = text;
    $(".ol").append("<div id='lo' style=background-color:" + 
      noteColors[index].value + ";></div>");
  </script>
</div>
```

The end result should be like this
[image]

Comment: Can you give an example of what the desired output would look like?

Comment: By the time the `append()` (with the background-colored `div`) runs, `index` will be past the end of the `noteColors` array.

Comment: @DanPrince i have added a img :-)

Comment: @PaulRoub How can i solve it? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start be rethinking the structure slightly, you probably don't want your script tag inside the element whose contents you are trying to replace.

In the interests of both speed an maintainability, it makes more sense to use the HTMLElement API to create your elements. This involves using methods like `document.createElement` and `element.appendChild` rather than building your elements as strings and using `.innerHTML`

Finally, adding some of the functional array methods to your code will do a lot to simplify your solution.

[`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) can be used to transform each item in an array, using a function of your choice.

[`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/foreach) can be used to loop over your array, without having to worry about index variables.

```
var items = noteColors.map(function(color) {
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.style.backgroundColor = color.value;
  return li;
});

var list = document.createElement('ul');
list.setAttribute('id', 'colors');
items.forEach(list.appendChild);

var wrapper = document.getElementById('note_colors_wrapper');
wrapper.appendChild(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're sleepy. As in my country 's still early, maybe I can help you.

What happened is that you messed up with your array . It is out of the script tag.

I advise you to use the code in the order as shown below .

```
<html>
<head>
...... your head code
</head>
<body>
... body code

<div id="note_colors_wrapper"></div>

... more body code 

<script>
var noteColors = [
    { name: "red", value: "#FF396D" }, 
    { name: "green", value: "#C6DD2A" }, 
    { name: "blue", value: "#55C7F0" }, 
    { name: "purple", value: "#F64FC2" }, 
    { name: "yellow", value: "#F6DC2C" }];

var index;
var text = "<ul id='colorss'>";

for (index = 0; index < noteColors.length; index++) {
    //Note that in a very simple way, I assign the color in the style parameter of the <li>
    text += "<li class='ol' style='background-color:" + noteColors[index].value + "'>""</li>";
}
text += "</ul>";
document.getElementById("note_colors_wrapper").innerHTML = text;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Test the code in https://jsfiddle.net/tLcxtmow/1/

Hope this helps.